# How to manage angularJS priority in Functions execution?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

#Context

`$scope.getAllEvents()` is getting an array from Firebase database within the 10 last events and put it in the `$scope.events` array. Then the function is sorting by date `$scope.events`. I'm initializing `$scope.spliceTab` and calling `$scope.spliceFunc()`.

`$scope.counterPub()` is triggered in HTML each time the ng-repeat `$index` is a multiple of 5. The function is storing in `$scope.spliceTab` each values of the `$index` which were triggered. Basically it's a tab where future new items locations are registered. Then i delete doubles and save results in `$scope.result`.

Finally, `$scope.spliceFunc()` is reading inside `$scope.result`, and insert into `$scope.events` new items where positions are stored into `$scope.result`.

#Running

At the start of my app, `$scope.events` is filled up but `$scope.result` from `$scope.spliceFunc()` stays empty. When I'm using the infinite scroll to load 10 more events, it is working but the `$scope.events.sort()` algorithm is working before `$scope.spliceFunc()`, so my new items are on the bottom of my list and not in the positions I want.

#Problem

I would like to run my app this way:

1. filled up `$scope.events` from Firebase
2. Sort `$scope.events` by date
3. ng-repeat in HTML and filled up `$scope.spliceTab` when triggered
4. Finally running `$scope.spliceFunc()` on the already sorted array `$scope.events`

What do you think, is this possible ?

```js
// FUNCTION TO GET EVENTS

$scope.getAllEvents = function() {
  if ($scope.listSiz === undefined) {
    $scope.listSiz = 10;
  }

  var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("events");
  $scope.events = $firebaseArray(ref.orderByChild('endDate').limitToFirst($scope.listSiz));

$scope.events.$loaded().then(function()
{
  $scope.events.sort(function compareNumbers(y, x) {
    var date1 = new Date(x.endDate);
    var date2 = new Date(y.endDate);
    return date1 - date2;
  });

  if ($scope.listSiz === 30) {
    $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
  }
  $scope.spliceTab = [];

  $scope.spliceFunc();
});
};

// FUNCTION TRIGGERED IN HTML

$scope.counterPub = function($index) {
  var modulo = $index % 5;
  if (modulo === 0) {
    $scope.spliceTab.push($index);

    // Delete doubles

    $scope.result = [];
    $scope.spliceTab.forEach(function(item) {
      if ($scope.result.indexOf(item) < 0) {
        $scope.result.push(item);
      }
    });
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};


// FUNCTION SPLICE

$scope.spliceFunc = function() {
  //        console.log("************* TAB ****************** =", $scope.result);

  angular.forEach($scope.result, function(value) {
    $scope.events.splice(value, 0, [{
      name: "toto"
    }]);
  });
};
```

```html
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list ng-controller="MCtrl">
      <ion-item ng-repeat="e in events">

        <!-- IF ADDS -->
        <div ng-if="counterPub($index) === true">
          Hello world !
        </div>
        <!-- -->

        <div>
          <img data-ng-src="{{ ::e.creatorAvatar }}">
        </div>

      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: `$firebaseArray()` is an async operation. You can get a promise from that and execute the remaining operations upon that promise being fulfilled.

Comment: Oh ! That fixed one problem, thank you. I added `$scope.events.$loaded().then(function()
` before the sorting algo and now when i'm using the infinite scroll the new item are well placed. However, at the first start `$scope.spliceFunc()` seems to be ignored, no items are added in my list... Could it be because of the init of `$scope.spliceTab = []` ?